# Java - How to Modify Arrays Separately When Using a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array made of two separate arrays.

```
      // slot1 = new int[][] { {Array1}, {Array2}}
    slot1 = new int[][] { {1, 2 ,3}, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

I'm trying to do two separate things.

1. I'm trying to print the contents of array **slot1** , but with a space between each array. For example, I want my output to be something like:

> 1 2 3 ----- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

**Note:** where I have the dashes, I'll actually be adding a space

2. I want to know how I would modify the values of each internal array separately?

For example, how would I change the value of index 5 in Array2? And add value 1? So that if I print slot1 array, my values should look like this?

> 1 2 3 ----- 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I have looked other questions related to this, but I haven't found a clear answer when working two a 2D array made of other arrays? Would ArrayList work best for this type of scenario?

Here is my complete Code

```
public class Sandbox {

    static int[][] slot1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sandbox.setCache();
        Sandbox.displayCache();
    }

    public static void setCache() {
        slot1 = new int[][] { { 1, 2 ,3}, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

    }

    public static void displayCache() {
        for (int i = 0; i < slot1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < slot1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(slot1[i][j] + " "); // How to add a space between i and j? 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that this is a beginner question.

To put spaces between the two arrays in slot1 you can proceed in this simple way:

```
public static void displayCache() {
    for (int i = 0; i < slot1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < slot1[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(slot1[i][j] + " "); 
        }
        System.out.print(" "); //Add spaces here using your preferred way
    }
}
```

But, you'd probably doesn't want the spaces after the last array, so this is another (better) way:

```
public static void displayCache() {
    if(slot1.length > 0) {

        for (int j = 0; j < slot1[0].length; j++)
            System.out.print(slot1[0][j] + " "); 

        for (int i = 1; i < slot1.length; i++) { //Note: now i = 1
            System.out.print(" "); //Add spaces here using your preferred way
            for (int j = 0; j < slot1[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(slot1[i][j] + " "); 
        }

    }
}
```

To remove the space at the end of each array last element, you can apply the same logic (this is a work for you).

To change a value in slot1 (using your example as example) you can do this:

```
slot1[1][5] = 1;
```